# iOS 16 - UI bug when keyboard showing while UIAlertController is presenting

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uialertcontroller, ios16

I have a problem that appears on my iOS app since iOS 16.

I have a UIAlertController presenting and when the keyboard appears, on iOS < 16 the keyboard is showing in front of the UIAlertController, but since iOS 16 the UIAlertController is moved up automatically.

Here is an example of the same app running on an iPhone 12 with iOS 15.5 (left) and iOS 16.1 (right):

[image: Example]

I tried on iOS simulators and real devices and got the same problem.

How can I reproduce the iOS < 16 behavior on iOS 16?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't customize `UIAlertController` (subviews, private properties)  but create your own class instead.

Comment: Is there a way to modify ```UIAlertController``` behavior when keyboard is showing?

Comment: From the doc: "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and doesn’t support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.". So create your own class is the best solution and future proof one.

Comment: Ok I'll do that then. Thanks for your help!